# How can you set card-title in bootsrap to an input from text area

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i have an card where the user text in the textarea then clicks a button to make it disappear and show as the card-title div but it wont register any input.

The card will be repeated multiple times so i need to make the event listener be able to differentiate between different cards.

What i have tried is the below jquery and some javascript like this:

```
let questionHeaderInput = document.querySelectorAll(".questionMainTextArea");
let questionHeader = document.querySelectorAll(".card-title");
questionHeaderInput.forEach(item => {
    questionHeader.innerHTML = item.value;
});
```

```js
$(".questionMainTextArea").on("change paste keyup input", function() {
  $(this).closest(".card-title").innerHTML = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="questionMainTextAreaContent">
      <div class="questionMainTextAreaContentArea">
        <textarea class="questionMainTextArea" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question title" dir="auto"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-title questionHeader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the jQuery version by first targeting the closest `.card-body` then find `.card-title`. You can not use `innerHTML` on a jQuery referenced object, you should use `.text()`. Also, attaching the event on `input` is enough.

**Demo:**

```js
$(".questionMainTextArea").on("input", function() {
  $(this).closest(".card-body").find(".card-title").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="questionMainTextAreaContent">
      <div class="questionMainTextAreaContentArea">
        <textarea class="questionMainTextArea" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question title" dir="auto"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-title questionHeader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```